# Akka Timeout exception but messages actually sent

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am working with a Scala 2.13 stack with the following technologies:

- play! framework 2.8
- akka typed 2.6.3
- alpakka kafka 2.0.3

An Akka-stream job reads event from Kafka, asks an actor to compute something, and based on the given response, produces new events back to Kafka.

The issue is the messages sent using the ask pattern seem to be consumed by the `QuestionActor` (below) **only when at least two messages are gathered by its mailbox and only one per message received**.

The weird behavior is:

t1

```
ref ? Question("tr1", 1, None, actorRef)
> AskTimeoutException(tr1)
```

t2

```
ref ? Question("tr2", 1, None, actorRef)
> [INFO] - Question request for tr1-1. Processing.
> AskTimeoutException(tr2)
```

t3

```
ref ? Question("tr3", 1, None, actorRef)
> [INFO] - Question request for tr2-1. Processing.
> AskTimeoutException(tr3)
```

I'm trying then to understand **why I observe this behavior and what I'm doing wrong**.

The akka-stream Kafka pipeline is:

```
Consumer
  .plainSource(consumerSettings, subscription)
  .map(DeserializeEvents.fromService)
  .filter(_.eventType == classOf[Item].getName)
  .via(askFlowExplicit)
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider()))
  .map(
    response =>
      new ProducerRecord[String, OutputItem](
        topics,
        OutputItem(response.getClass.getName, response)
      )
  )
  .log("Kafka Pipeline")
  .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
```

The decider is a supervision strategy, that resumes the job on `Serialisation` and `Timeout` exceptions; `askFlowExplicit` declares an ask request to an external actor and - hereby - I bumped with my issue.

```
val askFlowExplicit =
  ActorFlow.ask[OutputItem, Question, Answer](askTarget) {
    case (envelope, replyTo) =>
      val item = Serdes.deserialize[Item](envelope.payload)
      Question(item.trID, item.id, item.user, replyTo)
  }
```

The pipeline starts up on Play! application bootstrap

```
@Singleton
class ApplicationStart @Inject()(
    configuration: Configuration,
    questionActor: ActorRef[QuestionActor.Question]
) {
  private implicit val logger = Logger.apply(getClass)
  implicit val mat            = context
  AlpakkaPipeline.run(configuration, questionActor)
}
```

The actor is a simple typed actor belonging to the same actor system and - right now - it is only forwarding the request coming from the stream towards another service.

```
class QuestionActor(
    configuration: Configuration,
    context: ActorContext[Question],
    itemService: ItemService
) extends AbstractBehavior[Question](context) {
  import QuestionActor._

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = context.executionContext
  private implicit val timeout: Timeout = ...

  override def onMessage(msg: Question): Behavior[Question] = Behaviors.receive[Question] {
    case (context, Question(trID, id, user, sender)) =>
      log.info(s"Question request for ${msg.trID}-${msg.id}. Processing.")
        itemService
          .action(id, user)
          .onComplete {
            case Success(result) if result.isEmpty =>
              log.info("Action executed")
              msg.replyTo ! NothingHappened(trID, id)
            case Failure(e) =>
              log.error("Action failed.", e)
              msg.replyTo ! FailedAction(trID, id, user, e.getMessage)
          }
      Behaviors.same
  }
}

object QuestionActor {
  final case class Question(
      trID: String,
      id: Int,
      user: Option[UUID],
      replyTo: ActorRef[Answer]
  )

  def apply(itemService: ItemService, configuration: Configuration): Behavior[Question] =
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      context.setLoggerName(classOf[QuestionActor])
      implicit val log: Logger = context.log
      new QuestionActor(configuration, context)
    }
}
```

It is built using runtime DI and Play!

```
class BootstrapModule(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration)
    extends AbstractModule
    with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(new TypeLiteral[ActorRef[CloneWithSender]]() {})
      .toProvider(classOf[QuestionActorProvider])
      .asEagerSingleton()
    bind(classOf[ApplicationStart]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}

private class Question @Inject()(
    actorSystem: ActorSystem,
    itemService: ItemService,
    configuration: Configuration
) extends Provider[ActorRef[Question]] {
  def get(): ActorRef[Question] = {
    val behavior = QuestionActor(itemService, configuration)
    actorSystem.spawn(behavior, "question-actor")
  }
}
```

*What I tried*

- changing dispatcher to `QuestionActor`
- changing mailbox to `QuestionActor`
- run the pipeline from within the `QuestionActor`
- sending the same message from withing the actor constructor (to self), the same behavior observed: one further message will trigger the actor to consume the former, ask timeout for the latter.

*What I didn't*

- changing dispatcher to Akka stream pipeline

It looks to me as a threading problem right now, but I don't know where to go from here.
Any help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by just sending messages to the actor without integrating it into the flow?

Comment: It's hard to see where the problem is. But you have too many context defined. Try not to `extends AbstractBehavior[Question](context)`, avoid passing `context` as constructor argument, and just use `Behaviors.setup + receiveMessage`.

Comment: Hi Ivan, yes, I tried sending the same message to self from within the actor constructor, I can observe the same behavior. (even if I don't use ask). I updated the question.

Comment: Will try to avoid `AbstractBehavior`

Comment: Try replacing `msg.replyTo ! NothingHappened(trID, id)` with `sender ! NothingHappened(trID, id)`

Comment: Hi @ignasi35, nothing changes, it is the same ref. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're combining `AbstractBehavior` which provides `onMessage` and there you define a new `Behaviors.receive[Question]` behaviour. You have to use either one or the other.

Remove `Behaviors.receive` as following

```scala
  override def onMessage(msg: Question): Behavior[Question] = {
      log.info(s"Question request for ${msg.trID}-${msg.id}. Processing.")
        itemService
          .action(id, user)
          .onComplete {
            case Success(result) if result.isEmpty =>
              log.info("Action executed")
              msg.replyTo ! NothingHappened(trID, id)
            case Failure(e) =>
              log.error("Action failed.", e)
              msg.replyTo ! FailedAction(trID, id, user, e.getMessage)
          }
      Behaviors.same
  }
}
```

`AbstractBehavior.onMessage` is implementation of a behaviour. So, you receive a message via method argument, you're supposed to process it and return back a new `Behaviour`, `Behaviours.same` in your case.

But instead of processing the message, you create a new `Behaviour` with `Behaviors.receive` and register the callback of the Future to the original first message. Thus you see the log statement when second message arrives, which triggers the new behaviour.

If you want to use FP style definitions, you have to stick to `Behaviors.xxx` helper methods only. If you choose OOP style, then you extend `AbstractBehavior`. But you shouldn't do both.

Comment: Yep, seems to work: I moved to FP style actor instance, by defining the behavior within the `Behaviors.setup`. But I cannot fully grasp it: why defining the behavior using `onMessage` produces the issue?

Comment: Pretty neat! Thank you so much again!